# Is there any way to not to use exclude in the spring-boot-starter-data-jpa dependency and maintain the same storage?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am currently using the below dependency and getting 38MB JAR file and if i remove exclude,it is increasing to 41MB. Is there any possiblity to avoid exclude and maintain the lower MB?

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
             <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.activation-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion> 
                <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>     
                <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
                <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>antlr</groupId>
                <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
                <artifactId>jandex</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.dom4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Why are you interested in limiting the size of the JAR? I'm not saying it's bad (or good) thing, I just want to understand why you feel the need for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try manually add dependencies only you can plan to use. Probably your project's size decreases. Otherwise you're not able to decrease the size.